# My javascript code error

Tags: jquery, css, html

What is/are my jquery bug/bugs code?

```
    <head>
      <title>Untitled</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style_light.css" />
      <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sw").click(function(){
       if($(".onsw").css("background-image" , "url(../img/b.png)")){
           $("#lamp").removeClass("off");
           $("#lamp").addClass("on");
           $(".onsw").toggleClass("offsw");
       }
       else if($("#sw").css("background-image" , "url(../img/a.png)")){
           $("#lamp").removeClass("on");
           $("#lamp").addClass("off");
           $("#sw").removeClass("offsw");
           $("#sw").addClass("#onsw")
       }
      });
      });
      </script>
      </head>

    <body>

    <div id="lamp" class="off"></div>
    <div id="sw" class="sw onsw"></div>
    </body>

    body{
    background-color: black;
    }

    div{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:10px auto;
    background-size: 400px 600px;

    }
    .sw{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    }

    .on{
    background-image: url(../img/on.jpg);
    }
    .offsw{
    background-image: url(../img/a.png);
    }
    .onsw{
    background-image: url(../img/b.png);
    }
    .off{
    background-image: url(../img/off.jpg);
   }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sw").click(function(){
        $("#lamp").toggleClass("on off");
        $(this).toggleClass("onsw offsw");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your guide

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
   if($(".onsw").css("background-image") == "url(../img/b.png)"){
       $("#lamp").removeClass("off");
       $("#lamp").addClass("on");
       $(".onsw").toggleClass("offsw");
   }
   else if($("#sw").css("background-image") == "url(../img/a.png)"){
       $("#lamp").removeClass("on");
       $("#lamp").addClass("off");
       $("#sw").removeClass("offsw");
       $("#sw").addClass("#onsw")
   }
```

`$("#sw").css("background-image")` will give you the setted `background-image` property of the element.

Comment: Exactly, that's what i asked, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want tern on and tern off a light and change switch

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your code? Tell me if you can;y

Comment: sorry, I can not , but thank you for your guide anyway

Comment: You care to elaborate your issue a bit more then>?

Comment: I dont know what do I say

Comment: Hehe okay tell me what exactly you want to achieve in a more elaborative manner..